# How can I parallelize this bottleneck in my code?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pytorch

I am using pytorch for data processing, not for machine learning, etc.  This has resulted in a substantial performance boost, but I still have a bottleneck in the process.  Most of the time I am doing simple operations on large arrays, including boolean indexing.  However, at some point I need to compare the "final" array with values from another data set and find matches.  Something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import torch 

device = torch.device("cuda:0")

# make couple tensors
data1 = torch.rand((1000, 10), device=device)
data2 = torch.rand((1000, 10), device=device)

# do some arithmetic operations on tensors (real code has a lot more operations)
data3 = data1 * data2

# a dataframe was built previously and must be loaded.  Here a dummy dataframe is created
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0, 10, (10, 5)), columns=list("ABCDE"))

# define flag array
matchFound = np.full((8000, 1), False)


# now the bottleneck
for row, val in df.A.unique():
    # determine if anything in data3 is within 10% of "val"
    idx = (val >= 0.9 * data3) & (val <= 1.1 * data3)

    # if there are any matches then set flag value
    if idx.sum() > 0:
        matchFound[row, 0] = True
```

Everything up to the bottleneck point takes ~3-4 ms, but the bottleneck requires ~750 ms.  I need to pass through this ~18E6 times, making the total run time a couple weeks.  Is there any way I can speed this up?

What I have tried so far: I wrote a function to encapsulate the bottleneck region and pass it off to multiple CPUs using Process from multiprocessing (I also tried using Process from torch.multiprocessing).  The idea is to break this dataframe up into 15 chunks and send each chunk to a CPU thereby reducing the bottleneck time from 750 ms to 50 ms and my total runtime to 1d.  However, I keep getting a runtime error (RuntimeError: CUDA error: initialization error).  I don't understand what is causing this error (does CUDA just get angry when I pass tensors to multiple CPUs?).  Also, I think that by sending the data from the GPU to CPU takes more time than it saves.

Comment: [This](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/multiprocessing.html#sharing-cuda-tensors) might be a good resource for debugging the runtime error, which seems to be about contention for the GPU device from multiple cores.